# MS-SQL 2012 Synonym for Sequence

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

On Oracle I can create a synonym for a sequence of another user.
Is there a way to do this on MS-SQL 2012?

Comment: i think the syntax is used in both the ORACLE and SQl SERVER as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Synonym's on Sequences are not possible in MS SQL.

Answer (score 1):

The Sequences in Oracle is used for Columns that going to be autonumber; in SQL Server where the version is lower than SQL2012, you use IDENTITY Property, when you define the table, for example:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable
(
idColumn int IDENTITY(1,1),  
descColumn varchar(50)
)
```

**IDENTITY(1,1):** this sequence starts with 1, and is incremented by 1.

Meanwhile the new versions of SQL SERVER (2012 & 2014) you can create Sequences, check it here  [CREATE SEQUENCE (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091.aspx).

Comment: The question was not how to define an auto-increment column.